# How to create a primary key as A1/D-M/100000 in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

How to create a primary key as A1/D-M/100000 in SQL Server 2005 in Visual Studio 2008 ?

Comment: What parts of that key are fixed, which change from row to row?? E.g. where does the "A1" or the "D-M" come from? Are they the same for all rows? Do they change from row to row??

Answer (score 0):

Use `varchar(20)` as column type and generate the primary key value from the code.

Comment: When i use. ..int data type then incrememnt seed is 100000 and auto increment 1.... but i want in primary key it shows as A1/D-M/100000

Comment: Adrian's suggestion is spot on. I feel that you're not comfortable enough in SQL to be doing this yourself, so perhaps you should so some more reading on SQL and VB.NET, and get someone to help you in real life.

Comment: @Adrian, perhaps `char(14)` instead, simply because of the overhead of the additional 3 bytes per row for `varchar`?

Comment: @Randolph `varchar` won't take more space than the content

Comment: @Adrian, varchar will take the actual length of data plus 2 bytes (not 3 as I originally said). Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx for more.

Comment: @Randolph Yes, that's to be exact. I was under the impression you were saying varchar(x) always takes x bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not possible in SQL Server as requested, which makes me want to tell you to do some more reading.

However, you can achieve something similar by creating a primary key in Visual Basic, and storing that value in a `char` or `varchar` field in SQL, as suggested by Adrian Godong's answer.

That said, what **I** would do if this were my database, is create a normal PK using `int` or `bigint` (depending on how many rows I'm planning to store), and using a second column as `char` or `varchar`, with an appropriate index, to store the `Ax/D-M/xxxxxx` values.

What you are wanting to do is mix business rules with SQL Server's database rules, and that's a very bad idea. SQL does not care what your data looks like, so you should not force it to do so. Your business rules may change down the line, and this would be much easier to accommodate if you do a proper PK to start with, that does not rely on some arbitrary naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

What parts of that key are fixed, which change from row to row??

E.g. where does the "A1" or the "D-M" come from? Are they the same for all rows? Do they change from row to row??

If those parts are fixed, and only the big number in the middle needs to change, you could:

- define a column of type `ID INT IDENTITY(100000,1)` for the number
- define a **computed column** like this:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
     ADD YourPKField AS 'A1/D-M/' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(6)) PERSISTED
  ```

In that way, SQL Server would auto-increment your `ID` field, and `YourPKField` would contain the values:

```
A1/D-M/100000
A1/D-M/100001
A1/D-M/100002
A1/D-M/100003
....
```

and so on - automatically, without you doing anything more.

Answer (score 0):

Use an INT IDENTITY(100000,1) as your Primary key.
Add the calculated (displayed) key wherever you need it (queries...). It's decoration, and as such, it's part of the front-end, not of your data.